# Inherit from QDomNode to create PHP Code Fragments in a QDomDocument

Tags: php, qt, dom

I write a program which should output PHP code containing mainly basic HTML code but a few PHP commands. Therefore I wanted to use QDomDocument to write this file in an object oriented style.

I created a class QDomPHPCode inheriting from QDomNode. I've overwritten `save()` which writes the PHP code including the `<?...?>` to a QTextStream.

The problem now is that to create such an element, I have to call one of the factory methods `QDomDocument::create...()`, but of course, there doesn't exist one for my own class.

I thought about subclassing QDomDocument in order to implement such a method for my QDomPHPCode node and therefore watched the source code of QDomDocument. The functions `create...()` call the functions in QDomDocumentPrivate with the same name, so in order to implement an own create...() function implies the need to create one in QDomDocumentPrivate. The latter requires me to subclass QDomDocumentPrivate which isn't visible to `#include <QDomDocument>` and therefore can't be subclassed as far as I know.

Is there any possibility to do what I want to do? Or is it definitely the better (or only) way to create a PHP file completely on my own?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Privacy in C++ would be meaningless if you could do what you want to do here.  What do you ultimately want, a class that is a child of QDomNode and therefore gets its interface?  Obviously you could just subclass QDomDocument and add any create* method you want.

Comment: What's the reason for subclassing? QDom* is not designed for custom subclasses, there are no extension vectors, and I don't see anything you can reach that way you can't with composition instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that a **PHP document in not a valid HTML/XML document**, so you might have parsing errors. PHP is an interpreter that parses a special (PHP) document that could **produce a valid HTML/xHTML/XML document**.

So, as a workaround I suggest you place some tags say `<-- php-code-start -->` and `<-- php-code-end -->` into the document (using QDomDocument) and then parse/replace it after (**post-processing**).

Another approach is the replace the php start tag with an HTML start comment but you will still need to post-process.

Comment: I just thought about the same idea with the post-processing! :) Just started implementing this. Thanks! (By the way: parsing isn't needed)

Comment: ... but I didn't use two comments, one for start and one for end markers, but one single comment as a placeholder for the whole PHP code since the PHP code itself then doesn't get touched (encoded or whatever...) by the QDomDocument at all.